# Permissions manager

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

In Django Admin, I'm developing a permissions manager which consist in:

> Permissions - Role - Group - Users

- You can group users to assign roles to groups.
- A group can have multiple roles.
- The roles are composed of different permissions.

So far, my models look like this (I've created my own permissions but are not shown here):

```
class UserGroup(models.Model):
    """
    A group encompasses different users.
    A group can have multiple roles.
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)


class Role(models.Model):
    """
    A role is composed of permissions.
    The roles are applied to user groups.
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False)
    group = models.ManyToManyField(UserGroup)


class Permission(models.Model):
    """
    Permissions that are applied to roles.
    """
    role = models.ManyToManyField(Role)
    # ...
```

As this is the first time I work with permissions/roles I want to know if it's a good approximation or what are its weaknesses?

Should I create intermediary models/tables?

Answer (score 0):

Django has an authentication system with permissions

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/

then for better permission system on object level you can use django-guardian https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian or simillar application